# How to get translate property from a group?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I have a number of svg groups and each group has a number of children within them.

In case of a `click` on the `group` I would like to move all my groups with their children. I would like to know the `translate` properties of the `clicked` group, so I can move other groups.

I'm trying to get the `translate` property, but was unable to get it.

This is what I've tried:

```
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr({width:300,height:300});    
var group = svg.append('svg:g').attr({
    'width':100,
    'height':100,
    'transform' : 'translate(50, 50)'
});

group.append('circle').attr({'r':30});

group.on('click', function () {
    console.log(this); //how to get the translated properties?
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5w85zbzx/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robert's answer already covers how to solve the problem, but here's the D3 way of doing it in addition. In particular, you can use `d3.transform()` to parse the value of the `transform` attribute:

```
var t = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform"));
console.log(t.translate);
```

Updated jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5w85zbzx/2/);

Answer (score 5):

You can use getAttribute e.g.

```
this.getAttribute("transform")
```

or the [SVG DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedTransformList)

```
this.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix.e + ", " + this.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix.f)
```

baseVal.numberOfItems gets you how many components there are to the transform and [getItem(0).type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGTransform) gets its type i.e. 2 = translate in this case.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/5w85zbzx/1/) alerts 50, 50 for me on Firefox.

Comment: Can you please update on my `jsfiddle` please? since i am not getting the values as object. instead i am getting as `translate(50, 50)` from this string how will get the each of `x` and `y` ( which is x and y)

Comment: If you want them as objects, you want the SVG DOM which is the second alternative I gave in my answer.

Comment: Yes, i tried with applying the `2`, nothing consoled. can  you update in the fiddle please?

Comment: I did so, it's only a copy and paste of the answer though.